# Can one define informational content of a mathematical expression?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, philosophy, entropy

At least in physicist's thinking, information, vaguely, is something that allows one to select a subset from a set.

Say, a system can be in states A and B, we have done a measurement on it (extracted information), then it is in either A or B. Now we are able to say, in which state among all the possible states is the system in.

Now, consider numbers, say number e. One can write many digits to specify the boundaries of an interval to which e belongs. In fact, arbitrarily good precision can take arbitrarily large amount of information to specify the decimal representation of the number.

Now, however, one can also write an expression for e, say $e = \sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n!}$, and it seems like e is defined to an arbitrary precision straight away. That is to say, here we have something, for which we would have needed infinite amount of information.

The question then: does this expression contain infinity of information/any information at all? Or, can information be defined at all for expressions?

One might surely argue that given an expression, one still has to perform infinite number of evaluations to obtation a decimal expression of the number. But then a number of other questions would arrive: "Is it evaluations of faculties and additions then that produce information?", "Is the information only about decimal representations of numbers, but not the numbers themselves?", and perhaps many more.

Comment: Perhaps you want this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: @Potato: Indeed looks very relevent. Thank you (10^10 times)!

Comment: This is a very deep question. – Someone could write down a 50 places decimal number like $2.71828\ldots9$, and you might think this number contains a lot of "information". But this information is absolutely worthless unless you are told that this number is very near some number holding big secrets.

Comment: This will answer your question math.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/prove-there-are-no-hidden-messages-in-pi/ , if you have any more specific ones after reading that please refine your question.

Comment: Dear @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri, your link is really interesting and somewhat relevant to my question. However, it is far from obvious to me, how exactly does it provide the answer. Can you please kindly state it more explicitly?

Comment: All computable numbers contain the same information, because anyone can compute them to arbitrary precision. They can find any such closed form formula by brute force.

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri: So, is it meaningful to assign the concept of information to an expression? And why does the informational content of an expression (seemingly compact) seem to differ so much from that of an irrational number (seemingly infinite)?

Comment: Everything is "seemingly infinite", 1=1.00000...=1/2+1/4..., But not all strings can be defined in finite number of symbols. But to talk of the information they contain, you need to first specify a way (an algorithm), that interprets the information, ie asks the questions, if you only know the answer but not the question the answer is useless.

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri: Nevertheless, the concept of encoding seems so much more obvious, when applied to strings, rather than exressions. Latter tend to have a complex underlying structure. Saying 1.0000.. is not the same as writing all the zeros, for example. Here you use a convention, that zeros continue.

Comment: Yea, ok, so then your talking about the kolmogorov complexity, which is a well defined notion. Expressions are also strings.